# Code Igniter session not working on some servers

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i am relatively new to CI and working on a project. My issue is

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'error1');
```

fetched as

```
$this->session->flashdata('error')
```

works on one of my servers but not on others. I have tried checking all the code over n over but to no help, my session config is as below

on both servers the code is same, can someone help me out on what I could be missing on one server thats failing the session.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: Identical code on both servers behave different?

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: yes identical code behaving differently, am using database driver for the sessions. code igniter version 2.1.3

Comment: both same php version PHP 5.4.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured and had my issue sorted, as I went through the configs, i realized there is a cookie domain setting and when i changed that  to reflect the new domain, the sessions are back and i can now set and read the session flash data

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = ''
```

changed this value in the config file and all was ok.